# How to refresh velocity templates

Tags: java, velocity

How to refresh velocity templates after given interval. Let say i want it to automatically 
refresh after specified interval

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by _refresh velocity templates_?

Comment: I mean if i change text in it. It should be reflected in the next merge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try following;

```
Properties templateProps = new Properties();

templateProps.setProperty( "file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval", 60); // This is in seconds
templateProps.setProperty( "file.resource.loader.cache", "true" );

Velocity.init( templateProps );
```

Comment: Also you can use `velocity.properties` file, if you prefer to configure externally.